# Where does aws cli store profile information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'd like to set my aws cli to use a new AWS account on my machine.

So I backed up and deleted `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` files.

After the deletion, I typed `aws configure` to set the *Access Key ID* and *Secret Access Key* of the new AWS account.

But then I got an error saying

> botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile
>   (my_profile_name) could not be found

`my_profile_name` is the profile name of my old AWS account.

How does aws cli remember my old profile name?

How can I reset it so that I can use new *Access Key ID* and *Secret Access Key*?

I also find that typing `sudo aws configure` is able generate new `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` files.

But the [getting started tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) doesn't say that you need add `sudo` before `aws` command. So I don't think this is a good solution for my case.

The *profile* I mentioned in this post refers to a setting in `~/.aws/config`:

```
[profile my_profile_name]
region = ap-northeast-1
output = json
```

Comment: Maybe your $AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE env var is pointing to the old config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have set `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` environment variable or `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable.

See: [Configuration Settings and Precedence](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence)

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 3):

The AWS CLI look for AWS Credentials in a number of different places in the following order according to their [documentaion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html):
 1. provided as command line option
 2. environment variables
 3. The AWS credentials file (~/.aws/credentials)
 4. CLI configuration file (~/.aws/config)
 5. Instance profile credentials

So in your case, It is first checking the environment variables before checking your ~/.aws/credentials file and since you may have previously set environment variable it is taking that.

Also you can have multiple profiles for multiple aws account set up easily like:

```
$ aws configure --profile aws_account1
$ aws configure --profile aws_account2
```